# Windows Authentication not working on server

Tags: c#, asp.net, webserver

I'm developing a website in ASP.NET and C#.

I've created the website so when a user goes to the site, his windows client username is read out with:

```
System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name.ToString();
```

and then I lookup his username in the db and create a user object with all necessary data (team, name, permission level, role, ...) from the return data. 
Then I keep this object in a session var until the user logs out.

This was working like a charm locally but now that I've deployed to the server I get `defaultAppPool` for every user.

What am I doing wrong?

In my web.config file I have:

```
authentication mode="Windows"
```

I have to admit this is the first time that I'm doing the deploying myself and everything went smoothly except for this.

Comment: Have you also configured IIS to use windows authentication (and disable anonymous)?

Comment: really sorry but it was a really stupid mistake.

System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name.ToString(); 

needs to be 

HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;

This gives me the correct username.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you've discovered, `System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()` gives you the identity of the application pool.

You should be using `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity`.

Answer (score 2):

Windows authentication and IIS
If you select Windows authentication for your ASP.NET application, you also need to configure authentication within IIS. That’s because Windows authentication is delegated back to IIS. IIS gives you a choice of four authentication methods:

1. If you select anonymous authentication, IIS does not perform any authentication. Anyone is allowed access to the ASP.NET application.
2. If you select basic authentication, users must provide a Windows username and password to connect. This information is sent across the network in clear text, making basic authentication dangerously insecure on the Internet.
3. If you select digest authentication, users must still provide a Windows username and password to connect. However, the password is hashed before being sent across the network. Digest authentication requires that all users be running Internet Explorer 5 or later and that Windows accounts be stored in Active Directory.
4. If you select Windows integrated authentication, passwords never cross the network. Users must still have a Windows username and password, but either the Kerberos or challenge/response protocols are used to authenticate the user. Windows-integrated authentication requires that all users be running Internet Explorer 3.01 or later.

Answer (score 0):

Get current user identity as :

```
var userWinId = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity as WindowsIdentity;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

`System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name`

instead of

`User.Identity.Name`

or

`System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name`